# Why StartsWith is returning me a wrong item

Tags: android, string, compare, match

I'm using the method `String.startsWith` to compare 2 strings to see if one of them begins with the introduced characters.

**CODE**

```
List<Province> models;

public int getIndexIfStartsWith(String str){

    for(int index = 0; index < models.size(); index++){
        if(str.startsWith(models.get(index).getKey())){
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

I'm comparing against a list of provinces of Spain. If I put `14006` as a string to compare, the method iterate against a list of provinces with `key` (a number like "1", "28", etc) and `value` (name of province).

When I enter `14006` the method returns me the item `"1", "ALAVA"`, but "1" is not the same of "14" that is the begging of the compared value. ALAVA with a key length of 1, shouldn't be compared against "14" (the begging of the desired value).

Whats wrong??

```
compare 14006 against 1, ALAVA
                      2, ALBACETE
                      3, ALICANTE
                      ...
                      14, CORDOBA
```

Córdoba, 14006 should be the only match, but Alava is returned too.

I'm using this for left padding the number with zeros, so I can compare everytime against 2 digits.

```
public static String padLeft(String stringToPad, int padToLength){
    String retValue = null;
    if(stringToPad.length() < padToLength) {
        retValue = String.format("%0" + String.valueOf(padToLength - stringToPad.length()) + "d%s",0,stringToPad);
    }
    else{
        retValue = stringToPad;
    }
    return retValue;
  }
```

later, with this I use...

```
public int getIndexIfStartsWith(String str){

    for(int index = 0; index < models.size(); index++){
        if(str.startsWith(CommonUtils.padLeft(models.get(index).getKey(), 2))){
            return index;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: what is the type of models ? List of what?

Comment: Arraylist<Province> list ---> String Key, String Value. Key stores a number. I need to compare against this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your if is the wrong way around. When it tests on the first Province, `"1", "ALAVA"`, you are testing if `14006 starts with 1` which is true, when you want to test `1 starts with 14006` which is false, and will only pass when you will reach the `14006` key.

It should be

```
  if(models.get(index).getKey().startsWith(str)) { 
     ...
  }
```

**Note**

Your method returns only the first match, there might be several matches if you pass let's say `"2"`, maybe you should return a List.

But if you want a perfect match you should be using `equals()`

**EDIT** (After new requirements definition)

Given the following list of provinces:

```
List<Province> models = new ArrayList<>();
models.add(new Province("1", "ALAVA"));
models.add(new Province("2", "ALBACETE"));
models.add(new Province("3", "ALICANTE"));
models.add(new Province("14", "CORDOBA"));
```

You can make the following method to return the matching index

```
public static int getIndexIfStartsWith(String str){

  int matchingIndex = -1;

  // make sure we have at least 2 digits (left pad if needed)
  if(str.length() == 1) {
    str = "0"+str;
  }

  String first2Digits = str.substring(0, 2);

  for(int i=0; i<models.size(); i++) {
    String provinceKey = models.get(i).getKey();
    // make sure the province key also has at least 2 digits (left pad if needed)
    if(provinceKey.length() == 1) {
      provinceKey = "0" + provinceKey;
    }

    if(provinceKey.startsWith(first2Digits))
      matchingIndex = i;
  }
  return matchingIndex;
}
```

This returns ALAVA for "1" and "01" and CORDOBA for "14" and "14006"

Comment: Then, with this change, when compare 14 with 14006m the result will be false again, not?

Comment: no because you will be testing `if(14 starts with 14006)` which is false too. Change it and see if it does what you want. If you want a perfect match use `.equals` instead of `.startsWith`

Comment: I don't need a perfect match, but I need to compare only the 2 first chars of the string (if 14006 is entered, I will use only 14 for the comparation), then in this case 1 should never been a result, only items with 14.

Comment: ok so you requirement is that if you enter `14006 `, you return all the provinces with key starting with 14? and there can be several of them. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is the requirements. I'm so sorry for my english description.

Comment: Look up my EDIT in my answer, that should do what you want

Comment: Actually it is not clear, what should return if you enter 10005 ? the Province starting with 1 or 10? When is ALAVA ever returned?

Comment: Alava needs to be returned if I enter "01" or "1". The zp has 5 positions, the 2 first are for describe the province, so, I think that the number entered need to be filled with zero on left to complete. See my answer in the post.

Comment: I added your edit to your question. And amended my answer, have a try and see if it works now